# How can I fix Popopen requiring a \ before a space in the command on Macos?

Tags: python, macos

I'm writing a script in Python that takes the names of files from a config.txt and then uses popen to run a terminal command to check if they're installed. Here is my script currently:

```
import os

with open('config.txt') as config:
    programs = [line.rstrip() for line in config]




for program in programs:
    stream = os.popen('mdls -raw -name kMDItemVersion /Applications/' + program.strip() + '.app')
    target_version = stream.read()
    if "could not find" in target_version:
        read_out = program.strip() + " is not installed."
        print(read_out)
    else:
        read_out = program + " is installed, version " + target_version
        print(read_out)
```

For programs without spaces (Slack, for example), the output is fine:

```
Slack is installed, version x.y.z
```

However, if I input a program with a space such as Google Chrome, the popopen command is unable to find it. This is solved by writing the name as "Google\ Chrome".

Since I want this config file to be straight forward, I'd like users to not have to type \ before every space.

I already tried using the replace command to insert a \ before entering the command, and then removing it before printing the name, however it was seemingly not changing the output. Any advice on this?

Comment: Have you tried with `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `os.popen()`?

Comment: This would turn into something like this: `subprocess.Popen(['mdls', '-raw', '-name', 'kMDItemVersion /Applications/', program.strip() + '.app'])`